# Como buscar por um texto específico dentro da tag?

Tags: suporte, tags

Existe alguma maneira de procurar por um texto específico dentro do wiki/fragmento de tag? Como?

Por exemplo, eu pesquiso por "Esta tag" e deveria retornar todas as tags que existem o texto "Esta tag" no wiki/fragmento de tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não existe nenhuma funcionalidade disponível no site, entretanto pelo [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/new) é possível fazer uma consulta que busca algo pelo corpo da tag.

4 e 5 são respectivamente o fragmento e a wiki, a última coluna fornece o link já montado para edição.

```
SELECT t.tagname, p.id, p.body, 
'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/'+ CAST(p.id as varchar) +'/revisions' as link
FROM posts as p
INNER JOIN tags as t ON p.id = t.WikiPostId
WHERE PostTypeId in (4,5) AND  Body LIKE '%java%'
```

Comment: Ainda não está 100% essa consulta... falta pesquisar no fragmento logo acerto isso.